# elasticsearch's python client can't perform a query but requests does

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-requests

I can't get any result using elasticsearch's Seach API:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(['http://es-production1:9200', 'http://es-production2:9200', 'http://es-production3:9200'])
res = es.search(index="logstash-*", query={"match_all": {}}, size=1)
```

This returns an error `elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054,..., None, 10054, None))) caused by: ProtocolErrorConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054,..., None, 10054, None)))`

When I try the same query in `requests`, in the Kibana dashboard, or in Postman, it works perfectly.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://es-production1:9200/logstash-*/_search'
payload = json.dumps({"query": {"match_all": {}}})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Any hints why the own elasticsearch's client can't connect?

Comment: Proper URL for requests would be `http://es-production1:9200/logstash-*/_search`, the payload `{"query": {"match_all": {}}}` though it shouldn't cause `ConnectionResetError`. Do you have SSL enabled for the cluster maybe?

Comment: You are correct, I copied the strings wrong. But no, the cluster is not set up with SSL at the moment, and it is just the elasticsearch client that doesn't work. Accessing the data via requests works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a single endpoint, like `Elasticsearch(['http://es-production1:9200'])` ?

Comment: Yep, but it still has the same error...

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? Are you running code with `requests` on the same machine with same Python as code with the `elasticsearch` lib?

Comment: It's v7.8.0. The two codes (`requests` and `elasticsearch`) are both on my machine, and the cluster is running inside the same network but somewhere else

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas.

Comment: All good, let's see if anyone has other suggestions :(